# Extension of Hilbert Inequality for locall compact groups

Tags: inequality, reference-request, locally-compact-groups

The classical Hilbert inequality states that if $f,g\in L^2(0,+\infty)$, then
$$\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{f(x)g(y)}{x+y}dxdy\leq\pi\|f\|_2\|g\|_2.$$
Are there analogs to the inequality for locally compact groups?

Comment: How would you translate the $\frac{1}{x+y}$ part to an arbitrary group?

Comment: @lisyarus    Well perhaps as a product of inverses or even a quantitative version for a given say lie group with a suitable weight as a function of x and y.